# How to get the renderized child components in parent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My goal is to get only the visible child components in parent component.

Here is my pseudo-code failed aproach:

### parent.component.html

```
<parent (click)="changeVisibility()">
   <child *ngIf="visible1"></child>
   <child *ngIf="visible2"></child>
   <child *ngIf="visible3"></child>
</parent-component>
```

### parent.component.ts

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childs: ChildComponent[];
visible1: boolean = true;
visible2: boolean = true;
visible3: boolean = true;

changeVisibility(){
   this.visible2 = false;
}
```

Hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error if you use above code?

Comment: @Chellappanவ No, i just dont know how to detect the active child components

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you want is not clear but this is working fine.

If you want to check that, check it like below

.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.childs)
}
```

This will give you QueryList like below

```
QueryList {dirty: false, _results: Array[2], changes: {…}, length: 2…}
```

As you can see _results:Array[2] is of length 2. Example link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnuzvw

Comment: yes it will show only those which are active. Try setting *ngIf="false" from 2 selectors it will give you results count 1 in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @Mamta It works but if i bind a flag to *ngIf the result is always 3

Comment: @Elkin didn't get you can you please explain what you tried

Comment: @Mamta Check the updated question. The `ngAfterViewInit()` only runs once and if i put the code in `ngAfterContentChecked()` the length will always be 3 even when just 2 are visible

Answer (score 1):

type of `ViewChildren` is `QueryList`

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childs: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

there a Observable for `changes` and it will emit a event for changes.

```
this.childs.changes.subscribe(e => {
    console.log('changes', e);
    // Write your logic ...

    // i.e:
    // e.length
    // e.forEach(child => { ... })
 })
```